# packages have unmet dependencies: libegl1-mesa: Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 10.4.0-0intel1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 is to be installed

Tags: 14.04, package-management, intel-graphics, dependencies, ubuntu-drivers

This error I get during the installation of "Intel Graphics Installer":

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libegl1-mesa: Depends: libgl1-mesa-dri (= 10.4.0-0intel1) but 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4 is to be installed
libgl1-mesa-glx: Depends: libglapi-mesa (= 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4) but 10.4.0-0intel1 is to be installed
                 Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.6.2-1ubuntu2 is to be installed
                 Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.4-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Also, I have tried to install `mesa-utils` as follows:

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-utils

mesa-utils is already the newest version.
mesa-utils set to manually installed.
```

How should I proceed to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of the Graphics Installer are you using? The current one seems to support only Ubuntu 14.10. The [Intel Download Page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2015/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8) tells you that:

> *Beginning with the v1.0.8 release of the Graphics Installer, we discourage using the Graphics Installer with Ubuntu 14.04.*

Your error tells you that the installed version of a packet is not the one which the installer needs (for example **10.1.3-0ubuntu0.4** vs **10.4.0-0intel1**)

Comment: I edited this file "sudo gedit /etc/lsb-release"  i.e 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=trusty to 
DISTRIB_RELEASE=14.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=utopic
 because it was giving an error at the beginning of installiation.

Comment: the version is v1.0.8 which one should i install ?

Comment: According to the [Intel Page](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2014/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.7) version 1.0.7 is the one for 14.04. But note that it is not supported anymore and might make your system unstable. And you should **not** edit lines in some /etc/ file because it gives you errors. This error just told you that the installed program is not for your platform and you faked the platform by editing these lines...

Comment: I shall restore the following file. So is there any way to install Graphics Installer in 14.04.

Comment: In the last link it says that 1.0.7 is used for 14.04 - but it is an old release, so be aware that it receives no future updates and any bugs will probably not be handled.